# "Bad argument (train data must be floating-point matrix)" error

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I am developing an image classifier. I extracted features as pca. My sample code is

```
for file in listing1:
  img = cv2.imread(path1 + file)
  res=cv2.resize(img,(250,250))
  gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  xarr=np.squeeze(np.array(gray_image).astype(np.float32))
  m,v=cv2.PCACompute(xarr)
  training_set.append(v)
  training_labels.append(1)

trainData=np.float32(np.float32(xi) for xi in training_set)
responses=np.float32(training_labels)
svm = cv2.SVM()
svm.train(trainData,responses, params=svm_params)
svm.save('svm_data.dat')
```

But during training I am getting this error:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (train data must be floating-point matrix)
>   in cvCheckTrainData, file
>   ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp, line 857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution This worked for me**
You need to convert it in to np array and need to flatten that array.

```
for file in listing1:
 img = cv2.imread(path1 + file)
 res=cv2.resize(img,(250,250))
 gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 xarr=np.squeeze(np.array(gray_image).astype(np.float32))
 m,v=cv2.PCACompute(xarr)
 arr= np.array(v)
 flat_arr= arr.ravel()
 training_set.append(flat_arr)
 training_labels.append(1)
```

Training

```
trainData=np.float32(training_set)
responses=np.float32(training_labels)
svm = cv2.SVM()
svm.train(trainData,responses, params=svm_params)
svm.save('svm_data.dat')
```